# Linked List C++ Node

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is the code of linkedlist in c++ :-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void insertdata(int element ,node *head){

    node *newnode = new node();
    newnode -> data = element;
    newnode -> next = NULL;

    node *itr;
    itr=head;
    if(head == NULL)
    head = newnode;
    else{

    while(itr->next != NULL){
        itr = itr-> next;
    }

    itr->next = newnode;
}
}

void print(node *head){
    node *print = head;
    while(print != NULL){
        cout<<print->data<<"\n";
        print = print -> next;
    }
}

int main(){
    node *head = NULL;
    insertdata(10,head);
        insertdata(20,head);
            insertdata(30,head);
            print(head);
            return 0;
}
```

Which is not working it is working fine if i declare head as global object. What is the reason i have to declare it globally.i am 2nd year B.Tech Student learning it first time so its look confusing.

Comment: You should format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, arguments of functions are **passed by value**, so modifying the arguments in callee won't affect local variable of caller.

References can be used to modify caller's local variable.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void insertdata(int element ,node *&head){

    node *newnode = new node();
    newnode -> data = element;
    newnode -> next = NULL;

    node *itr;
    itr=head;
    if(head == NULL)
    head = newnode;
    else{

        while(itr->next != NULL){
            itr = itr-> next;
        }

        itr->next = newnode;
    }
}

void print(node *head){
    node *print = head;
    while(print != NULL){
        cout<<print->data<<"\n";
        print = print -> next;
    }
}

int main(){
    node *head = NULL;
    insertdata(10,head);
    insertdata(20,head);
    insertdata(30,head);
    print(head);
    // do delete what you created via new
    while(head != NULL){
        node *next = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is no need to declare the node with class key class. It is more natural to declare it with class key struct. For example

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
```

As for the function `insertdata` then function parameters are its local variables. Any changing of a local variable does not influence on the original object used as the argument.

So you should declare the second parameter either as reference to `node *` as for example

```
void insertdata( int element, node * &head );
```

or as pointer to `node *`

```
void insertdata( int element, node **head );
```

In the first case the function definition can look like

```
void insertdata( int element, node * &head )
{
    node *newnode = new node { element, nullptr };

    if ( head == nullptr )
    {
        head = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        node *itr = head;
        while ( itr->next != nullptr ) itr = itr->next;
        itr->next = newnode;
    }
}
```

In the second case the function definition can look like

```
void insertdata( int element, node **head )
{
    while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;

    *head = new node { element, nullptr };
}
```

Take into account that usually new nodes are inserted in the beginning of  singly-linked lists.

Also it is better when the first parameter refers to the head of the list.

Here is a demonstrative program that based on using the second function definition.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
};

void insertdata( node **head, int element )
{
    while ( *head ) head = &( *head )->next;

    *head = new node { element, nullptr };
}

std::ostream & print( node *head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( node *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->data << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}


int main()
{
    node *head = nullptr;

    for ( int x : { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } ) insertdata( &head, x );

    print( head ) << std::endl;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```